# DataGridView AutogenerateColumns false does not update DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource

I have a DataGridView whose DataSource I set programmatically.

In order not to show all columns, AutoGenerateColumns is set to false and all columns are manually added, 2 lines of code for each column

```
        dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView.DataSource = _bs = new BindingSource() { DataSource = someObject };
        dataGridViewColumns.Add("Count", "Anzahl");
        dataGridView.Columns["Count"].DataPropertyName = "Count";
```

I can then edit data in the datagridview. But later when checking the content of someObject, it has not updated.

I also tried

```
_bs.ResetBindings(true);
```

without any improvement.

What do I have to do additionally to write back the changes to the datasource?

Note: Same code is working if I set AutoGenerateColumns to true and I do not add columns manually.

Comment: Do you change context after update?

Comment: Add the Column(s) before you set the DataSource. I assume this: `dataGridViewColumns.Add("Count", "Anzahl");` and this: `dataGridView.DataSource = _bs = new BindingSource() { DataSource = someObject };`  are typos (2 in 4 lines of code?). Anyway, it's quite better if you post real code.

Comment: @Jimi Initializing columns first did not change anything. I only see 1 typo, dataGridView.Columns? And I cannot make edit for just 1 char.. will think of you to edit it.

Comment: @ShervinIvari How do I change context? Which update?

Comment: The data source context, if its working with autogenerated columns why not just hiding them?

Comment: @ShervinIvari Actually, I am googling hiding those now. I remember from previous attempts, that I cannot just hide them before they are generated (so form load event was too early) and my search was in vain a few weeks back where I had the same problem and ended with AutoGenerateColumns false. DataGridView was readonly back then though.

Comment: I had the same problem, I find solution by changing dbContext.on that time I was using same dbcontext and datasource only notify when a record add.I'm not sure if caching is your problem

Comment: Actually, I had a typo in the code too, in the databound property. I never noticed since it regularly comes in empty, only noticed when I tried to set autogenerated columns to invisible with same column name and it didnt exist.

Comment: Change the code in: `dataGridView.Columns.Add("Count", "Anzahl"); dataGridView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Count"; _bs = new BindingSource(someObject, null); dataGridView.DataSource = _bs;`. This assuming that `Count` is actually the bound Property/Field name, not the DGV Column name and `_bs` is an instance field.